# Meteor waiting for method call in komposer container before subscribe

Tags: reactjs, meteor, containers

So I want to call a method to check if the component should be subscribe or not but i had tried many way and it failed.

```
let container = (props, onData) => {
   Meteor.call("check", (err,res){ res return true and false
      if(res){
        const sub = Meteor.subscribe("data");
        if(sub.ready()){
           onData(null, data);
         }
      }
   });
}
```

but the sub.ready() in call back would always false but if i subscribe outside the call back it work but I don't want to subscribe to every component that check method return false

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble with something similar. My workaround was to not do any too many tasks from within the callbacks. Please check if something along these lines works:

```
let container = (props, onData) => {
        // a simple flag
        var canSubscribe = false;

       Meteor.call("check", (err,res){ res return true and false
          if(res){
            canSubscribe = true;

          }
       });
        //moved this outside of the callback.
        if(canSubscribe){
                 const sub = Meteor.subscribe("data");
                 if(sub.ready()){
               onData(null, data);
             }
    }
}
```

Comment: i had tried the code but it call meteor.call every second and so the res was never set to true

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment very clearly.. Are you saying that the meteor method is being called every second? - Do you have a timer function somewhere or is the container function being called reactively?

Comment: so sorry it was another problem, but the code 
        if(canSubscribe){
                 const sub = Meteor.subscribe("data");
                 if(sub.ready()){
               onData(null, data);
             }
didn't get called since canSubscribe is always false. when canSubscribe = true is set in the method it didn't recall the container